# iPad 4 stuck in update/restore loop

Tags: ipad, itunes, software-update, restore

I have an iPad 4 running 9.3.1. I put it in recovery mode and connected it to my PC. Now iTunes keeps telling me to update or restore it, but regardless of whether I click "update" or "restore", it never fully completes - it runs for a little bit, and then the same window pops up.

Can I get past this screen, or is it bricked forever?

Alternatively, is it possible to force it to update to only iOS 10? Im wondering if itunes is trying to force it into the latest iOS version, which is not possible with ipad 4...

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to a Mac, or an Apple Store? The problem may be the Windows iTunes .exe, not the iPad.

Comment: I tried my roommates MacBook air, but iTunes doesn't work on new macOS versions. I tried installing older versions and i just keep getting the message that it is not compatible with this version of macOS.